# Band calculations and sorting within a specified geometry

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, landsat-8, sorting

I am working on a small geographic area (< 50 km sq.) and am trying to find the 5-10 least cloudy Landsat images for my specified area. The issue I have is that if I simply use:
imageCollection.filterBounds(geometry).limit(5, 'CLOUD_COVER'), I get the images that are least cloudy across their entire area (10000+ km sq.), but these are not the least cloudy images for my specific area of interest.

Does anyone know of a function I can to do these sorts of calculations within my specific area of interest only?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, using `.limit(5, 'CLOUD_COVER')` will give you a list of the 5 images with lowest `CLOUD_COVER` values in the collection, but this property relates to the total cloud cover within the whole image. If you need to sort the image collection based on the cloud cover over a specific region of interest (ROI), then you will need to compute it.

Here's one suggestion to achieve this with the `LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2` collection:

```js
var dataset =ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2")
.filterBounds(roi)
.filterDate(startDate, endDate)

/*
Function maskL8sr from the Examples/Cloud Masking/Landsat8 Surface Reflectance script
modified to return the "cloudFree" band. 
*/

function maskL8sr(image) {
  // Bit 0 - Fill
  // Bit 1 - Dilated Cloud
  // Bit 2 - Cirrus
  // Bit 3 - Cloud
  // Bit 4 - Cloud Shadow
  var qa_mask = image.select('QA_PIXEL').bitwiseAnd(parseInt('11111', 2)).eq(0);
  var saturation_mask = image.select('QA_RADSAT').eq(0);

  // Apply the scaling factors to the appropriate bands.
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);

  var cloudFreeMask = qa_mask.min(saturation_mask)

  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
  .addBands(thermalBands, null, true)
  .addBands(cloudFreeMask.rename("cloudFree")) 
}

function reduceMask(img){
  // Reduce the "cloudFree" band to get a fractional value of 
  // how much of the ROI is free of clouds based on QA_PIXEL and QA_RADSAT
  return img.set({
    "roiCloudFreeFraction": 
    img.select("cloudFree").reduceRegion({
      reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry: roi,
      scale: 120,     // adjust based on your ROI size and other considerations.
      bestEffort:true
    }).get("cloudFree")
  })
}

dataset = dataset
.map(maskL8sr)
.map(reduceMask)
.limit(5, "roiCloudFreeFraction", false) // sort descending because we want the highest cloudFreeFraction.
;
```

and here's a demonstration applied over a small ROI in the UK:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/a2be1e774723c80e216aa5232ee3fcf0

The idea is to use the `maskL8sr` function as in the [Examples/Cloud Masking/Landsat8 Surface Reflectance](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=Examples%3ACloud%20Masking%2FLandsat8%20Surface%20Reflectance) example script, but modified to return a band indicating cloud-free pixels (1) or cloud-masked pixels (0). A second function (`reduceMask`) assigns a new property called `roiCloudFreeFraction` to each image. The value of `roiCloudFreeFraction` is computed with [image.reduceRegion()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-reduceregion). Depending on your ROI's size and other factors, you can adjust the scale at which you want this reduction to be computed.

Finally, we can use the same strategy of `.limit()` to sort the image collection and return the X images with the highest `roiCloudFreeFraction` by setting the `ascending` option to false.